# What are the limits on myopia for a pre-eye refraction surgery for a class 1 medical certificate?

Tags: medical, dgca-india-regulations

Are there any limitations for myopia (-number) for a pre-eye refraction surgery for a class 1 medical certificate? I live in India & I have -6.5 & -7.5 in the left & right eye respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It [looks like there are no limits for](http://dgca.nic.in/aic/AIC13_2008.pdf) your *pre-surgery* eyesight:

> Flight crew having undergone refractive surgery will be considered for
>   medical fitness for flying on a case-to-case basis. Such cases will be
>   examined only after a minimum period of six months after the
>   procedure. Medical fitness for initial issue of licence may also be
>   considered for such cases, if the visual requirements for the license
>   category are met with normal corneal topography, no post surgical
>   complications like corneal opacity interfering with vision and
>   unstable refraction.

That makes sense: LASIK physically changes your eyes, so whatever your values were before the surgery are completely irrelevant after it. The general [class I eyesight requirements](http://dgca.nic.in/cars/D7C-C1.PDF) in India are taken from [ICAO Annex 1](http://www.icao.int/safety/airnavigation/nationalitymarks/annexes_booklet_en.pdf), which isn't freely available online. However, ICAO's [Manual of Civil Aviation Medicine](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/8984_cons_en.pdf) says:

> Distant visual acuity with or without correction shall be 6/9 or
>   better in each eye separately, and binocular visual acuity shall be
>   6/6 or better. No limits apply to uncorrected visual acuity.