# Is there a limit for which vision can be corrected to 20/20 vision for being a pilot?

Tags: pilots, medical, dgca-india-regulations

I have 20/400 vision and can be corrected to 20/20 vision with glasses. 
Does having 20/400 vision disqualify me from getting a pilot license? 
Would it prevent me from getting the required medical certificate?

Comment: *prevent me from getting a medical certificate?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: India. If you don't know the regulations for India, tell me for any country.

Comment: [You can find the answer for the US/FAA regulations here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/can-a-pilot-use-glasses-to-meet-the-faa-required-20-20-vision)

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27732/62)