# What are the eyesight requirements for a medical certificate in India?

Tags: medical, dgca-india-regulations

Does it matter what your eye power is, if your vision can be corrected to 6/6 (20/20) vision?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27732/62). You might also like to mention what class of medical you're asking about (if you know), because the requirements can be different for different classes.

Answer (score 1):

The DGCA's [relevant requirements](http://dgca.nic.in/medical/med-rule-ind.htm) adheres and refers to ICAO Annex 1 (see pages 3 and 4). Here's the relevant text from Annex 1:

#### Class 1

> 6.3.3.2 Distant visual acuity with or without correction shall be 6/9 or better in each eye separately, and binocular visual acuity shall be 6/6 or better. **No limits apply to uncorrected visual acuity.**

#### Class 2

> 6.4.3.2 Distant visual acuity with or without correction shall be 6/12 or better in each eye separately, and binocular visual acuity shall be 6/9 or better. **No limits apply to uncorrected visual acuity.**

(Emphasis mine.)

The above is for the requested uncorrected visual acuity, but it is not the full text, e.g., if the correction is surgical, there is more fine print to read.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in India 6/6 and corrected vision is preferable for eye vision in basic criteria in physical examination, I m not sure if vision is not correct closely they will grant the permission.

But might be link will help you:
http://dgca.nic.in/aic/AIC13_2008.pdf